# IDE can't recognize cryptography module, how do i fix this?

Tags: installation, module

I'm creating a password holder, as a beginner project. I keep running into this error, where everytimg i use the commant `from cryptography.fernet import Fernet` Now this worked for the person in th video with no issues. I ensure you I have installed the cryptography module before trying this. Yet, I keep getting the no module found error. Would appreciate some help.

I have tried simple things, such as copying the code from pypi/cryptography website. Yet nothing has happened.

I have also tried installing it on the command line, as well as my IDE terminal, no difference there.

I have checked if cryptography supports my python version (3.11.2) and it says on pypi that it does.